# jQuery undefined error using FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am using this http://fancybox.net/

When I do

```
$('a.#div1').trigger('click')
```

to popup a fancybox, it gives me this error (using Firebug)

opts.itemArray[opts.itemCurrent] is undefined
 if (opts.itemArray[opts.itemCurren...[opts.itemCurrent].title.length > 0) {\r\n
jquery.f...-1.2.1.js (line 345)

Why is that? Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.#div1')
```

selects an anchor tag with class name #div1. I think the selector is invalid. Thats probably the reason for the error.

'.' is a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html) and '#' is [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors).

If you want to select an element with id div1 then you can write like this

```
$("#div1")
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of this:

> $("a.div1").trigger("click");

or

> $("a#div1").trigger("click);

or

> $("#div1").trigger("click");